# Django url kwargs in templates

Tags: python, django

Previously we have been accessing `kwargs` in Django templates with `{{view.kwargs.kwarh_name}}`.

However, it has been to my surprise that this is not working in my django 3.2.4+
Has it been removed, is there any issue with the line above?

Note: Kwargs here I mean something like below:
Given a function as below:

```py
def GetSomething(request, code):
   return render(request, "some template here")
```

Now, the urlpatterns would be something like,

```py
import GetSomething from .views

app_name = "some_app_name_here"
urlpattern = [
   path("link/<int:code>/", GetSomething, name="some_cool_name") #http:localhost/link/12345/
]
```

Now in HTML/Django templates or Jinja2(whichever you use), accessing this code would be via `{{ view.kwargs.code }}`

But it so happens that this is not working for me in Django 3.2, any reasons??

Hope I was very clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The get_context_data method of class based views adds the view to the context as view. If you have a function based view, it will not be added to the context automatically. This is not related to Django versions 3.2.4+

So either use a class based view or use a function based view and pass the kwargs to the template through the context variable.

```
def GetSomething(request, code):
   context = {
       #some values here
       'code':code,
   }
   return render(request, "some template here", context)
```

Then you can access your context variables in the template directly.

```
{{code}}
```

Comment: Thanks @yagus but don't you think we should really access the `view` even on function views! I think I will raise it on the django core admin mailinglist and get what they say, otherwise thatnks